# rotas which turn text into number

Tags: excel

I have a weekly rota in excel, and what I would like to do is if a cell contains any text ad 70 in another cell
so if cells a3,b3,c3,c4 all have text but c5 does not the total would be 280. is there any way of doing this?
I have tried conditionally formatting but won't return number, and I am struggling with the 'if' function.

Comment: Can you clarify whether the cells with or without text all in the same row plz? More generally, plz give us an actual example with all the cells filled in and say what formula you tried. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

In general:  `=counta(myRange)*70`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `COUNTIF()` function. It would also help you to add criteria for calculation.

```
=COUNTIF($A$4:$C$5,"<>")*70
```

[image]